# How to get files from Serilog

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hello I need to get the logs from iOS. I have used DependecyService and I have initiated the logger in iOS

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.NSLog()
    .CreateLogger();
```

But how do I get the files for example in text forms?

I have tried this, but nothing is there. where does the Serilog actually stores the logs on iOS? What Folder

```
public string GetLogFolder()
        {
       

 var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        documents = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrls(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.User)[0].Path;
        return Path.Combine(documents);
      
        }
```

Comment: you are using the NSLog sink, which writes to the iOS System Log, which you an view with XCode

Comment: @Jason but I would like to see them in txt file or display it on xaml

Comment: then you should use a different sink that writes to a file

Comment: and can you please advise which one

Comment: because I thought that I can get them from the device just with this sink